# shell scripting to automate login to all servers

Tags: shell, scripting, automation

I am trying to execute a script in another Ubuntu 16.04 box from my Ubuntu box.
When I do ssh from one to another, i.e.

```
ssh 10.1.2.3 -l tester -p 2222
```

It is asking me for:

```
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Then, it is asking me to input the password:

```
tester@10.1.2.3's password :
```

Is there a way to input this automatically?

I have 6 ubuntu servers in an environment and I have execute the script automatically in all server automatically by logging into one server.

"We have same custom port, password for all our servers"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Do you understand the purpose of the authorized_keys facility provided by ssh?

Comment: @nithi : You could use [Tcl/expect](http://www.neilbittner.com/automated-login-script-using-expect/).